# How to mute this AVFoundation player error "AppName[1188:30594] [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <...>" in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui, avfoundation, avaudioplayer, xcode11

How to mute this AVFoundation audio player error "AppName[1188:30594] [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x6000034f1900> F8BB1C28-BAE8-11D6-9C31-00039315CD46"  in SwiftUI ?

Here's my audioPlayer method

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

var audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!

func play(soundName: String, soundType: String){

    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: soundName, ofType: soundType){
    
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    
        do {
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
            audioPlayer.volume = 1.0
            audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        
            audioPlayer.play()
           }catch{
             print("....Couldn't find the sound....\(error.localizedDescription)")
         }
    }
}


func stopPlaying(){
    audioPlayer.stop()
}
```

It plays the audio file but crashed my mac sound system twice while playing sound in the simulator and I had to restart my computer and it became normal again. (Xcode 11.6)

THE ERROR:

```
"2020-08-19 09:56:28.261745+0600 AppName[1188:30594] [plugin] AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id <CFUUID 0x6000034f1900> F8BB1C28-BAE8-11D6-9C31-00039315CD46"
```

Need a solution to fix this error!

Comment: I experience this problem in much simpler scenario. Mac, Obj-C  -  calling  [[NSSound soundNamed:@"Purr"] play];  whether "Purr" is a public system sound - will play once, and emit the exact same log line - then will not play again. So the question is NOT in the AVPlayer layer - it's lower. Maybe we should initialise some sub-system, or I-don't-know-what.

Comment: What I really mean here, is the phrasing of the question is wrong. This is not an AVFoundation player error - it's comes from a lower-level Subsystem than AVFoundation

Comment: Well how do we mute it?

Comment: The message is informational and unrelated to the sound system crash. The message "AddInstanceForFactory: No factory registered for id" occurs in apps using AVFoundation while running on a simulator, presumably because simulators weren't created in a factory. The message will not be displayed if the app is run on a device.